# How to check if user granted permission to read health data?

Tags: ios, healthkit, applehealth

I would like to check if the user has granted my app permission to read data from HealthKit.
I am aware that the official documentation reads that it's not possible due to privacy reasons, however apps like Google Fit or Garmin Connect do it somehow and Garmin Connect event shows a button that redirects to Settings -> Privacy & Security -> Health:
[Garmin Connect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G8tzG.jpg)
[Google Fit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gp50D.jpg)

How do they do that? Some kind of hack or special permissions from Apple?

Comment: How about `HKHealthStore().authorizationStatus` for a particular type?

Comment: @son it does not work for read permissions, only for write - which may indeed be the way Garmin Connect checks for the status, however Google Fit has only read permissions. What I also observed is that Google Fit shows the status basing only on permission to read steps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Health Kit reading permission status](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48336135/health-kit-reading-permission-status)